# Backbone model#destroy thru Collection#each does not iterate through all models correctly

Tags: backbone.js, model, destroy

My model

```
app.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: '',
        checked: false,
        price: 0
    }
});
```

Collection

```
app.ItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: app.Item,
        localStorage: new Store('itaaatems')
    });
```

I create a simple collection that has the model 'Item'.

```
app.itemCollection = new app.ItemCollection([
    new app.Item({title: "webb dev", checked: true, price: 100}),
    new app.Item({title: "drawing", price: 200}),
    new app.Item({title: "corn harvesting", price: 750}),
    new app.Item({title: "pen spinning", price: 50}),
    new app.Item({title: "pen spiddnning", price: 50}),
    new app.Item({title: "shark riding", price: 2000})
]);
```

I save each of them and see the success callback.

```
app.itemCollection.each(function (item){

    item.save(null, {success: function () {
        console.log('good');
    }
});
});
```

Everything looks good as I see each item as a model

```
app.itemCollection.each(function (item){
            console.log(item);
});
```

But when I try to delete them and for some reason after deleting the 3rd item, it hits a undefined. The 4th item is not defined for some reason while the first 3 I get success callbacks.

```
app.itemCollection.each(function (item){
    item.destroy({success: function (model, response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're iterating over an array and modifying it at the same time. Your `app.itemCollection.each` is little more than:

```
for(var i = 0; i < app.itemCollection.models.length; ++i)
    app.itemCollection.models[i].destroy({ ... });
```

in disguise and each `destroy` call will change the `app.itemCollection.models` array behind your back. If you keep an eye on the collection as you're deleting things:

```
app.itemCollection.each(function(item) {
    console.log(app.itemCollection.toJSON());
    item.destroy({ ... });
});
```

you should see the iteration appear to skip items.

You could iterate backwards and use [`Collection#at`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-at) and a for-loop:

```
for(i = app.itemCollection.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    app.itemCollection.at(i).destroy({ ... });
```

or use [`toArray`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) to get a copy of the underlying array of models and iterate over that:

```
app.itemCollection.toArray().forEach(function(item) {
    item.destroy({ ... });
});
```

Comment: Agree, or use `while (app.itemCollection.length > 0) { app.itemCollection.at(0).destroy(); }`